# Get a property of a anonymous type object from ListViewItem's prop Tag

Tags: c#, listview, object

I have created a new ListViewItem an have assigned an unitializated object to its Tag property:

```
                            // Here, anonymous type object
newListViewItem.Tag = new { XPATH = FindXPath(node) };
```

I have tryed to recover its XPATH property like:

```
// Recover Tag property on myObj
Object myObj = myListView.Items[0].Tag;
// Store XPATH property
string xpath = myObj.XPATH;
```

But I get error: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Status suppressed. Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'XPATH' nor is there any method of extension 'XPATH' that accepts a first argument of type 'object' (is there any using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I have tryed this same method with an declared object and it works, but with undefined object is not working. Sample code working:

```
// type object (class Xpath)
newListViewItem.Tag = new Xpath(FindXPath(node));
Xpath myObj = (Xpath)myListViewMostrarXML.Items[0].Tag;
string xpath = myObj.XPATH;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Well you could use `dynamic` as the type of `myObj`, potentially... Note that this is an anonymous type, not an uninitialized object. It's also unclear why you don't just set the `Tag` property to the XPath expression directly - why do you want to use an anonymous type? And why are you casting it to `Object`? (Both of your casts are unnecessary.)

Comment: Casting is dued to tries I have done. I am new on C# and I do not know if it was necesary. I will delete them. Ok, I will change uninitialized and anonymous type, thank you

Comment: It's still not clear why you're using an anonymous type at all though - could you give more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course. I wanna assign an annonymous type object to ListViewItem Tag property. The reasson of that is depending content of ListViewItem, Tag property will store differents objects (each object will have distincts fields), so I need anonymous type objects instead of declare so much classes

Comment: What benefit do you think you'll get from using anonymous types, that justifies losing type safety? If you use regular named types (which are dead easy to write, if they're just a bunch of automatically implemented properties) you can cast to that type then you retrieve the tag. You'll then get a descriptive exception immediately if the cast proves to be wrong, rather than a dynamic property access failure which doesn't provide nearly as much information.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes, you are right, then I will take it in mind and I will change structure. Also I will create that objects as you recommend me. Also, I have used `dynamic` and It works! It was great. Answer my question with that and I will choose you, of course. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use dynamic typing to do this:

```
// NOTE: NOT RECOMMENDED; SEE BELOW
// Populate the tag as before
newListViewItem.Tag = new { XPATH = FindXPath(node) };

// Recover Tag property using a variable of type dynamic
dynamic myObj = myListView.Items[0].Tag;
string xpath = myObj.XPATH;
```

However, I'd strongly recommend that you *don't* do that. You'd only be using dynamic typing to avoid having to declare a few classes, each of which is trivial to create anyway. For example:

```
public class XPathTag
{
    public string XPath { get; set; }
}

// Populate the tag using the class. You could add a constructor
// accepting the XPath if you wanted
newListViewItem.Tag = new XPathTag { XPath  = FindXPath(node) };

// Recover Tag property using a variable of type dynamic
XPathTag tag = (XPathTag) myListView.Items[0].Tag;
string xpath = tag.XPath;
```

Now if you fetch a tag from a control that has a non-XPathTag tag, you'll see an exception indicating exactly what's wrong. Additionally, there's no chance of getting typos when accessing the properties, as you could with the dynamic typing solution... the compiler will check how you use the tag.

Fundamentally, C# is almost entirely a statically typed language. Embrace that, and create types where you want to be able to reliably refer to specific sets of data. While there's still the cast that can fail, that's a a single point of potential failure which will be a lot easier to diagnose than the dynamic typing approach.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly that object is not uninitialized, you are creating an anonymous type and assigning it to `Tag` property. The type of tag is already object so you don't really need to cast it to `object`.

You want to access the property later on but you get an error because that property is not declared on `Object` class. C# is a type-safe language, meaning you can't access a member (method or property) if it isn't declared on a type.

In order to access it you have to cast `Tag` property to the type that has `Path` property but you can't because you don't know it's name. It's not actually anonymous, it has a compiler generated name but that is not visible to you. So you will need to create a type with relevant properties and use it instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. I will take it in care.